# Pan Zoom JQuery functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML and Javascript**

```
<section>
     <h1>Panning and zooming with CSS3</h1>

    <div class="parent">
        <div class="panzoom">
            <img src="image1" width="400" height="400">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="zoom-in">Zoom In</button>
        <button class="zoom-out">Zoom Out</button>
        <input type="range" class="zoom-range">
        <button class="reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        (function() {
            var $section = $('section').first();
            $section.find('.panzoom').panzoom({
                $zoomIn: $section.find(".zoom-in"),
                $zoomOut: $section.find(".zoom-out"),
                $zoomRange: $section.find(".zoom-range"),
                $reset: $section.find(".reset")
            });
        })();
    </script>
</section>
```

I'm using the Pan Zoom plugin.

```
https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom
```

How to limit the Zoomout functionality. I meant that I want to zoomout the image to certain size of the image like 100 px.

**Demo**
http://timmywil.github.io/jquery.panzoom/demo/#inverted-contain

I have tried the `Inverted containment within the parent element (to hide what's behind)`
 from the Demo. But for me its not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is old, but if you play with the minScale you can get what you like.
you can read the documentation on the README file :

https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will work for you

```
 (function() {
    var $section = $('section').first();
    $section.find('.panzoom').panzoom({
      increment: 0.3,
      minScale: 0.8,
      maxScale: 1.3
  });
```